# Angular 4, unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have one component which consists of one method which internally calls service and I need to do unit testing for the same.

**Component.ts:**

```
constructor(
    private formUtils: MeasureFormService,
}

getList() {
    this.formUtils.getList()
        .subscribe((data) => {
            this.memberDetails = data.MemberDetails;
            this.chaserDetails = data.RelatedChaserDetails;
        }, error => {
        });
}
```

**MeasureFormService.ts:**

```
getList() {
    return this._httpWrapperService.Get('../../../../../assets/json/overread-accept.json')
    .map((data: any) => {
        return data;
    });
}
```

I need to unit test the component method which calls service.

Comment: you should be faking the service call and spy it

Comment: You have to isolate the component and mock the service. Just use a mock class as the service.

Comment: Please post the code you have already tried. If you did not try anything, read the testing guide in the Angular documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
describe('Test', () => {

  let component: NotificationComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<YourComponent>;
  let measureFormService: MeasureFormService;
  let mockMeasureFormService;
  let listSubject;

  beforeEach(async(() => {

    listSubject = new Subject < any > ();
    mockMeasureFormService = {
      getList: () => {
        return listSubject;
      }
    };

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [YourComponent],
      providers: [{provide: MeasureFormService, useValue: mockMeasureFormService}]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(YourComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    notificationService = TestBed.get(NotificationService);
  }));

  it('should have a list of objects you need', () => {
    component.getList();
    listSubject.next(//just put a test object you are getting from the service);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.memberDetails).toEqual(//service response);
  });

});
```